# acro package - key 'acro/first-long-format' missing

Tags: acro

I try to use the option `first-long-format` of the `acro`-package. However, it fails to compile when this option is enabled.

Here the hopefully correct MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{first-long-format = \itshape} 

\begin{document}
Test. 
\end{document}
```

The logfile:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)  (format=lualatex 2022.5.29)  10 JUN 2022 17:56
 restricted system commands enabled.
**acro.tex
(./acro.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-03-18 3.21 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-02-24.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2022-02-24.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.119
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2022-05-04>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count183
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count184
\c@sapage=\count185

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen137
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks18
)
\sa@box=\box50
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro/acro.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-05-04 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: l3keys2e 2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: acro 2022/04/01 v3.8 typeset acronyms and other abbreviations (CN)
\l__acro_tmpa_int=\count195
\l__acro_tmpb_int=\count196
\l__acro_tmpc_int=\count197
\l__acro_tmpd_int=\count198
Loading module `base' ...
Loading module `interface' ...
Loading module `aux' ...
Loading module `properties' ...
Loading module `acronyms' ...
Loading module `formatting' ...
Loading module `ppfixes' ...
Loading module `tools' ...
\l__acro_minimal_usage_int=\count199
\l__acro_nest_int=\count266
\g_acro_barrier_int=\count267
\g_acro_barrier_total_int=\count268
Loading module `commands' ...
\l_acro_nest_level_int=\count269
Loading module `templates' ...
Loading module `list' ...
Loading module `pages' ...
\l__acro_pages_seq_threshold_int=\count270
Loading module `locale' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
Package: translations 2022/02/05 v1.12 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages
 (CN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count271
))
Loading module `pdfsupport' ...
Loading module `patch' ...
Loading module `definitions' ...
Loading module `upgrade' ...
)

! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'acro/first-long-format' is unknown and is being
(LaTeX3)        ignored.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \acsetup{first-long-format = \itshape}
                                        
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \acsetup{first-long-format = \itshape}
                                        

The module 'acro' does not have a key called 'acro/first-long-format'.
Check that you have spelled the key name correctly.




Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 5160 strings out of 477742
 100000,460012 words of node,token memory allocated 375 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 dir, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 3 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 3 attribu
te_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:16,3:2,4:1,5:1,7:2,9:3
 25853 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 72i,0n,73p,199b,44s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Could you point me to my mistake? I am puzzled actually.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no _option_ `first-long-format`, only an acronym _property_ `first-long-format`

Comment: There is the option `format/first-long`, though

Comment: Thank you (also for the great package itself)! It works now. I could almost swear that above code worked back in December.

Comment: @17757970 You are correct, it was previously an option, but at some point it was changed to the format/first-long style.